# Can't push to myProject.visualstudio.com anymore

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-repos

I'm running into the login hell of Microsoft again.
For a few weeks I can't push to my 5 year old repo at myproject.visualstudio.com anymore.
I can't log in. When trying to login using the browser I can't either. It keeps saying the repo doesn't exist.
When using Chrome's incognito browser I can log in into the repo and see all files.

I also have access to another project admin account. When I use that account to login I'm redirected to dev.azure.com and a different (newer) project is listed.

In VisualStudio 2017 I'm logged in with the account I also used in the incognito browser. When I push, I'm prompted to login again and then I get this error:

```
Pushing develop
Error: cannot spawn /d/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2017/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
could not read Username for 'https://myProject.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://myProject.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MyApp

Failed to push to the remote repository.
```

I have no idea how to continue and why `git-askpass.exe` is suddenly needed/missing.
I still commit my code daily but haven't been able to push for 3 weeks now (last successful push was Jan. 22).

Not sure if related but I normally use Atlassian SourceCode to commit and push and updated to the latest version (v3.3.6) mid-January. Around that time I also had trouble pushing to repos on GitHub using a completely different account. I fixed those by setting the credentials again in SourceTree. SourceTree, like Microsoft, can't handle multiple accounts very well. SourceTree still had trouble with my visualstudio.com account but I still could push using VS2017 for 10 days or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @eric-smith also suggested I already installed the newest GIT Credential Manager, but that didn't solve my problem.
I had also installed the latest GIT client and tried `GIT push` on the command line.
And ... my files are pushed. Not sure why.

I went back to SourceTree and noticed it was using the embedded version of GIT which was older (lower version number) then my command-line version. So I switched to the system version and now I can push in SourceTree as well.

And without changing anything else I can commit in VS2017 again as well.

I'm still puzzled what was going on. But I'm very glad it is working again.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the git credentials stored in Credential manager windows-> `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager` or mac in the `secure keychain` and follow the VS tool specific workflow to login and connect to the repo so they get recreated. More about git credential storage [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).

It looks like `git-askpass.exe` is related to the [git credential manager](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows). I would also try and upgrade or reinstall that tooling.